# How exactly to DELETE items from a List of entities without losing the correct index

Tags: c#, for-loop, entity-framework-5

I am using `Entity Framework 5` with Code First and `Repository pattern`. My `Delete` method looks like this :

```
public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Remove(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I have an entity in `1:N` relation with another one :

```
public class Page
  {
    public int PageID { get; set; }
    //other properties...
    public virtual List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }
  }
```

If I have an entity `Page` with 6 `Cell` entities related to it if I want to delete some of the cells according to some condition like this one:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < page.Cells.Count; i++)
   {
     if (page.Cells[i].RowNum == RowNum)
       {
         unitOfWork.CellRepository.Delete(page.Cells[i]);
       }
   }
```

each time the condition is true and a `Cell` is deleted, the List is modified and if in the beginning I have 6 cells and `page.Cells.Count` is 6 and my cells are like `Cell[0]`, `Cell[1]`..`Cell[5]` when I delete an item the List is updated `page.Cells.Count` returns 5 and my Cells are reindexed from 0 to 4 but now my counter `i` no longer matches the index of the `Cell`.

What I've done is to reset the counter each time an item is deleted:

```
if (page.Cells[i].RowNum == RowNum)
  {
    unitOfWork.CellRepository.Delete(page.Cells[i]);
    i = -1;
  }
```

which force the `for-loop` to start from the begining each time I delete an item (in other word the List is reordered). But I find this not very efficient. Since I'll be working with small volumes of data it's not that big of a problem but I wonder is there another (better/proper) way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly seen that if you go through the list from the first to the last item and delete an item it might be that you miss some items. Your solution of diminishing `i` by 1 after a match is correct but not optimal. A better solution is to traverse the list from the end to the start then the index always points to the correct item:

```
for (int i = page.Cells.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (page.Cells[i].RowNum == RowNum)
    {
        unitOfWork.CellRepository.Delete(page.Cells[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, man, another mystery revealed. I was wondering why I see this reversed variant in some cases.. Thanks a lot and have a happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the framework creates the `List<Cell>`. If the order of items is deterministic and won't change when you delete items then you can simply reverse your for-loop like this:

```
List<Cell> list = ...;
for (int idx = list.Count - 1; idx >= 0; idx--) {
    if (someCondition(list[idx])) {
        removeItem(list[idx]);
    }
}
```

If the order of list items is not guaranteed to remain unchanged you could first find all the items you want to delete, and then in a second pass delete them:

```
List<Cell> list = ...;
List<Cell> itemsToRemove = new List<Cell>();
foreach (var item in list) {
    if (someCondition(item)) {
        itemsToRemove.Add(item);
    }
}

foreach (var item in itemsToRemove) {
    removeItem(item);
}
```

Obviously this second case can be written more nicely with the Enumerable extension methods.

Comment: Nice idea, but with entity framework it enough to reverse the order as @xxMUROxx said. But this may come in hand in other similar scenarios. Thanks a lot and have a happy new year.